# How can I create multiple rewrite rules under one ruleset in Azure Application Gateway using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-application-gateway

We are trying to create azure application gateway rewrite rule using PowerShell. The issue is couldn't create multiple rule under one ruleset. Can someone help this issue.

```
#Get the AAG Config
$appGW=Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name "A3D0DVAPIAGW01ET" -ResourceGroupName "A3D0DVAPIRSG01T"
#Add the new Rewrite Rule

$json = @"
{
"Rules": 
    [
        {
            "Name": "DDO",
            "Path": "/etp/{var_request_uri}",
            "Pattern": "/ddo/*"
        },
         {
            "Name": "AM",
            "Path": "/efp/{var_request_uri}",
            "Pattern": "fsamtpf/*"
        }
    ]
}
"@
$rewriteRules = ConvertFrom-Json $json

foreach ($ruleset in $rewriteRules.Rules)
{
$urlConfiguration = New-AzApplicationGatewayRewriteRuleUrlConfiguration -ModifiedPath $ruleset.Path
$actionSet = New-AzApplicationGatewayRewriteRuleActionSet -UrlConfiguration $urlConfiguration
$condition = New-AzApplicationGatewayRewriteRuleCondition -Variable "var_request_uri" -Pattern $ruleset.Pattern -IgnoreCase
$rule = New-AzApplicationGatewayRewriteRule -Name $ruleset.Name -ActionSet $actionSet  -Condition $condition
$result = Add-AzApplicationGatewayRewriteRuleSet -Name "BWL_Rewrite" `
                        -RewriteRule $rule.ProvisioningState. `
                        -ApplicationGateway $appGW

$appGW | Set-AzApplicationGateway
}
```

[I need  to add multiple rules under one ruleset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0kuL.png)

Comment: What is the error you are facing? @utthira balaji

Comment: @Jahnavi When i add rules into AGW ruleset .powershell throws below error
Add-AzApplicationGatewayRewriteRuleSet : RewriteRuleSet with the specified 
name already exists
At C:\APIM_Powehsell\AGW_RewriteRuleSet.ps1:31 char:11
+ $result = Add-AzApplicationGatewayRewriteRuleSet -Name "BWL_Rewrite"`
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzApplicationGatewayRewrite 
   RuleSet], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.AddAzureApplica 
   tionGatewayRewriteRuleSetCommand

Answer (score 0):

> We are trying to create azure application gateway rewrite rule using PowerShell. The issue is couldn't create multiple rule under one ruleset. Can someone help this issue.

There is an issue in your code. Instead of specifying `$rule.ProvisioningState`, you should provide the `$rule` object, and for the `-name` parameter, use `$ruleset.Name`.

Here is the updated **PowerShell** Code to create rewrite rules in **Application Gateway**.

```
# Get the AAG Config
$appGW = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name "<>Gateway-Name>" -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>"

# Add the new Rewrite Rule
$json = @"
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Name": "Ruleset",
            "Path": "/etp/{var_request_uri}",
            "Pattern": "/ddo/*"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Ruleset2",
            "Path": "/efp/{var_request_uri}",
            "Pattern": "fsamtpf/*"
        }
    ]
}
"@
$rewriteRules = ConvertFrom-Json $json

foreach ($ruleset in $rewriteRules.Rules) {
    $urlConfiguration = New-AzApplicationGatewayRewriteRuleUrlConfiguration -ModifiedPath $ruleset.Path
    $actionSet = New-AzApplicationGatewayRewriteRuleActionSet -UrlConfiguration $urlConfiguration
    $condition = New-AzApplicationGatewayRewriteRuleCondition -Variable "var_request_uri" -Pattern $ruleset.Pattern -IgnoreCase
    $rule = New-AzApplicationGatewayRewriteRule -Name $ruleset.Name -ActionSet $actionSet -Condition $condition
    $result = Add-AzApplicationGatewayRewriteRuleSet -Name $ruleset.name -RewriteRule $rule -ApplicationGateway $appGW
   }
$appGW | Set-AzApplicationGateway
```

Once the above code is run, the rewrite rules are created in application gateway.

[image]